# Passing By ref and out

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

So if I am iterating using a foreach loop and I have a function inside that takes an argument of the object iterated from list, and lets say i set its value to be different.
Why don't I have to use out or ref ? I thought it was only passed by value if it you didn't use out or ref.... I know that a ref you must have initialized the variable before and out you just have to have set its value before return from the method.

It seems like if you a iterating thru a list and pass an object in its actually passed by reference. Consider the following example.

Example

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();
            list.Add(new Foo() { Bar = "1" });
            list.Add(new Foo() { Bar = "2" });



            foreach (var f in list)
            {
                Foo f2 = f; 
                Console.WriteLine("SetFoo Pre: " + f2.Bar);
                SetFoo(f2);
                Console.WriteLine("SetFoo Post: " + f2.Bar);

                Console.WriteLine("SetFooRef Pre: " + f2.Bar);
                SetFooRef(ref f2);
                Console.WriteLine("SetFooRef Post: " + f2.Bar);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }




            Console.WriteLine("");

            int i = 0;
            // Not using ref keyword
            Console.WriteLine("SetI Pre: " + i);
            SetI(i);
            Console.WriteLine("SetI Post: " + i);

            // Using ref keyword
            Console.WriteLine("SetRefI Pre: " + i);
            SetRefI(ref i);
            Console.WriteLine("SetRefI Post: " + i);
        }


        private static void SetRefI(ref int i)
        {
            i = 3;
            Console.WriteLine("SetRefI Inside: " + i);
        }

        private static void SetI(int i)
        {
            i = 2;
            Console.WriteLine("SetI Inside: " + i);
        }

        private static void SetFooRef(ref Foo f)
        {
            f.Bar = String.Format("{0} :: {1}", f.Bar, "WithRef");
            Console.WriteLine("SetFooRef Inside: " + f.Bar);
        }

        private static void SetFoo(Foo f)
        {
            f.Bar = String.Format("{0} :: {1}", f.Bar, "WithoutRef");
            Console.WriteLine("SetFoo Inside: " + f.Bar);
        }
    }


    class Foo
    {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
```

Output:

> SetFoo Pre: 1 SetFoo Inside: 1 ::
>   WithoutRef SetFoo Post: 1 WithoutRef
>   SetFoo Pre: 1 :: WithoutRef SetFoo
>   Inside: 1 :: WithoutRef :: WithRef
>   SetFoo Post: 1 WithoutRef :: WithRef
>
> SetFoo Pre: 2 SetFoo Inside: 2 ::
>   WithoutRef SetFoo Post: 2 WithoutRef
>   SetFoo Pre: 2 :: WithoutRef SetFoo
>   Inside: 2 :: WithoutRef :: WithRef
>   SetFoo Post: 2 WithoutRef :: WithRef
>
> SetI Pre: 0 SetI Inside: 2 SetIPost: 0
>
> SetRefI Pre: 0 SetRefI Inside: 3
>   SetRefI Post: 3

I understand the ref with the integer example but not the above Foo object iteration example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *reference* is passed by value. So the method can still change the contents of the object, it just can't change which object your variable refers to.

See [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for a lot more information, along with my article about [reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html).

Comment: So in the case above, I am pass a refence of the object Foo to my SetFoo methods. Since it shares the sames memory location, if I make a change to a value of Bar, the value of Bar will be the same of that instance of Foo in the list after exiting my function ? So there is no need for my SetFooRef method then ?

Comment: It is still different, you pass and object by reference value rather than object reference pointer (so to speak) if your are not using ref modifier. Your SetFooRef can be usefull if, say, you will construct a completely new Foo object inside the method - this new object will be "seen" outside the method. In contrast, without ref, you can change object properties, etc. and those changes will be "seen" outside, but if you initialize a new Foo object on a parameter variable - it will only have local scope as you will overwrite reference value.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense. So for the integer example I am passing it by value with SetI() but set SetRefI() I am passing by reference pointer then ?

Comment: With SetRefI you are passing the argument by reference, yes. Don't start using the word pointer, it'll only confusing things :)

Comment: OK, well I guess i was just confused on why not using ref on int changing the value inside the function will not be reflected outside, but passing an object without ref the changes would be see post function

Comment: gmcalab: Have you now read the value type / reference type page I linked to? That should have cleared things up a bit.