# C#: does using ref/out for a method parameter make any difference if an object variable is being passed?

Tags: c#, parameters, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing By ref and out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644372/passing-by-ref-and-out)

C#: does using ref/out for a method parameter make any difference if an object variable is being passed?

In C#, an object variable passes only a reference to the method, which means it is already a ref/out parameter.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Lasse: that question refers to a specific scenario, my question asks about the issue generally. I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: Read Jon Skeets answer, and check the link he posted to his article on the subject.

Comment: @Lasse: that there is an answer to that question that would answer my question does not make my question a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The instance is passed by reference. The pointer to the instance is passed by value, though.

If you use `ref`, the pointer is passed by reference as well - therefore you can use:

```
private void CustomDispose(ref object x) { x.Dispose(); x = null; }

CustomDispose(ref someInstance.someField);
```

someInstance's field will be assigned to null. It might be useful in Disposing via a custom method for example.

Comment: The instance is not passed by reference, it *is* a reference type.

Comment: Lasse V. Karlsen: Well, the instance itself is not passed at all. I just meant that it's like it was being passed by reference. For practical example it's like it's being passed by ref but instead the pointer is passed that contains a reference to the instance. That is why I have also included the pointer in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this question is just a pet peeve of mine, it has come up so many times on SO now that I think we should be able to get the semantics exactly right by now.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: Nothing to be sorry about. You are right that the semantics in my answer are not perfect. I just thought that it is clear enough to understand what exactly goes on there.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm the first part of your question:

- when dealing with an object (instance) in .NET, you always deal with 2 entities: the actual, anonymous object and the named reference to that object. That reference is a field, variable or parameter.
- You cannot pass the object instance as a parameter at all, you can only pass the reference.
- You can pass a reference by reference, meaning you can make it point somewhere else

```
void SetNull(ref MyObject parameter)  
{ 
   parameter = null;  // would make no sense w/o the ref
}
```