# C# passing List parameter

Tags: c#

If I am writing a method that accepts two list parameters like so:

```
public void ModifyYourListsHere(List<MyClass1> list1, List<MyClass2> list2)
{
    ...add and remove from the lists
}
```

Should I pass these as `ref` or `out` if I want the caller to understand that the lists will be modified? Or do I just need to document the method? Or should the user expect that they might be modified?

Comment: Since you pass a List and not a plain IEnumerable, you tell the caller that you need those functions a List provides, otherwise why would you require a List as parameters.

Comment: I think the most you can do is to name your method well :) (and of course: document it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing By ref and out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644372/passing-by-ref-and-out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use `out`, since that implies you will be assigning the variable before leaving the method (the compiler will actually enforce this).

`ref` will allow you to reassign the passed in parameter (definitely confusing to a user). You almost certainly don't want to use this either.

The best approach is to first, choose a good method name that makes it obvious the contents of one or both lists will be modified. Then use /// comments so that users of the function can see a more detailed description in Intellisense.

In case you are interested, the MSDN documentation for [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) and [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

Comment: `ref` will definitely *do something*, but I agree that what it does is irrelevant to this question. It is entirely legal and useful to use `ref` with reference type parameters.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, was checking MSDN when you posted. Updated to fix, please let me know if I missed anything. Thanks again!

Comment: Better to fix it because I red twice to understand why you said that `ref` doesn't matter.

Comment: @Inanikian, was there something else I missed? I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @Servy:`ref` can't be used here?

Comment: There's no point in using `ref` as the inputs are already reference types, so the modifications will be visible to the caller anyway.

Comment: @martin_costello, Actually there is, if you wanted to assign the passed variable to a new list. Without ref, that change wouldn't propagate to the caller. With it, the changes do propagate. Not that anyone should ever do this of course, but it would make a difference. See the linked documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Use ref if the function may change which List the variable points to and the caller shall reference the new list.

Use out if the function returns a new List that the caller didnt have a reference to before the call. This should only be used if the function needs to return multiple values.

If the List always exists before the function call you should not use either `ref` nor `out`.

Always document well if you function modifies the objects it receives as parameters!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first list to be modified then you have to use the `ref` keyword and the caller will know that he must use the `ref` before the list otherwise the method will be underlined by a red line saying that there is an error.

### Update

You can also use the ref keyword to pass reference types. Passing a reference type by reference enables the called method to modify the object to which the reference parameter refers. The storage location of the object is passed to the method as the value of the reference parameter. If you change the storage location of the parameter, you change the storage location of the underlying argument.  Source:[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Comment: You do not need to use the `ref` keyword to mutate the list.

Comment: Servy is correct you don't need to use `ref` to modify a list that is passed in. The list is itself a list of object references not the actual object itself. So passing in the list by reference would only pass a reference to the list of references. Passing by ref would allow that list itself to be reassigned not the items it contains.