# C# byte array is affected throu Method without reference

Tags: c#, sockets

This is a working (useless) example to receive data with a asynchronous Socket.
The complete code can be found at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx).

```
public class Class1
{
    private static void Receive( Socket client )
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        //state.buffer is a empty byte array
        client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar )
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;

        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        //state.buffer contains now all the received data.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

public class StateObject
{
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Inside the `BeginReceive` Method it should be impossible to affect the `state.buffer` field because there is no `ref` or `out` keyword.

But the byte array has in fact a changed value.

How is it possible that the `state.buffer` field is empty in `Receive` Methode and then contains all the received data when accessed in the `ReceiveCallback` Method?

Comment: In this case, the `buffer` is an array. The array reference itself is unchanged, but the *contents* of the array are still mutable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing By ref and out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644372/passing-by-ref-and-out)

Comment: How is it a useless example if it works properly?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I just added useless because the content of the StringBuilder is not beeing returned to be used or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it should be impossible to affect the state.buffer field because there is no ref or out keyword

No. This is not true. The actual object that `state.buffer` points to can be changed by another method, but its *reference* cannot be.

Here's a simple example:

```
static void Main()
{
    byte[] arr = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    ChangeTheObject(arr);

    foreach(byte b in arr) {
         Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}

static void ChangeTheObject(byte[] arr)
{
     arr[2] = 7;
}
```

`Main()` will print

```
1
2
7
4
5
```

The object itself can be changed by the method that receives it.

---

However, you can't change the reference itself.

```
static void ChangeTheReference(byte[] arr)
{
     arr = new byte[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
}
```

This will not change the contents of the original array in `Main()` because you've reassigned the local reference to a new object. You did not change the original object. That's where the `ref` keyword would come in handy.

---

The methods in your example are changing the array's contents, not the reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you took the time to at least *read* the comments on the MSDN link you posted, you would understand what's happening:

**Begin receiving the data from the remote device.**

```
client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, 
     new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
```

**Read data from the remote device.**

```
int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
```

Next time, take more time to read and understand what's already explained before claiming what's possible or not.